# CSV headers to a dictionary key - no modules can be used?

Tags: python

I have a csv

uid, place, time, lat, lon

1,place1,5:05,40.000,180.000

2,place2,6:05,40.000,180.000

3,place3,6:03,40.000,180.000

4,place4,7:03,40.000,180.000

5,place5,5:34,40.000,180.000

I want to have the headers as the key in the dictionary, and them to reference the values below each. I get to the part where I split the headers into 1 line, and then I get stuck. I can't use any module for this task.

Any insight would be so helpful.

```
cityInfo = {}
file = open('Ctime.csv', 'rt')
headers = file.readline().replace('\n','')
headers = headers.split(',')
print(headers)
for line in file:
    fields = line.split(',')
```

Comment: a general tip: dict, list, ... are builtins don't assign new values to them. this can lead to hard to track down errors later on if used in a different context.

Comment: oh yeah good point, I should change that in this question

Comment: before iterating through your columns you want to dome something like this: `yourdict[columnname] = []` for each column create a list and then fill it.

Comment: you never use your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

`zip` the headers and fields in each row together to append them to your dict of lists.

```
def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        headers = file.readline().replace('\n','').split(",")
        r = {header: [] for header in headers}
        for line in file:
            fields = line.replace("\n", "").split(',')
            for header, field in zip(headers, fields):
                r[header].append(field)
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
with open("Ctime.csv", "rt") as file:
    headers = file.readline()[:-1].split(",")
    result = {header: [] for header in headers}
    for line in file:
        values = line[:-1].split(",")
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            result[headers[i]].append(value)
```

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal.  Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users.  Code-only answers may be downvoted.